# Currency Value accross 2 objects

Tags: apex

I have 3 objects i'm working with (Case, Opportunity, and Custom object Expenses). the common denominator between all 3 objects is AccountID.

```
List<Account> acctRecords =[select Id,
                     (SELECT Id, Status, CaseNumber, AccountId FROM Cases),
                     (SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunities),
                     (SELECT Id,Name FROM Expenses__r)
                     FROM Account
                     Where Id ='some Account ID'];
```

I've wrote the SOQL query above and it pulls EXACTLY what I need. However I do need to combine/sum about 30 different fields between Opportunities and Expenses__c and put the value in a currency or text field in Case.

Comment: Have you tried to do any summing yourself yet? If so, that would be helpful to include in your question. Is there a master-detail relationship between `Account` and `Expenses__c`? Do you want to update **all** of the `Cases` related to your given `Account`, only one, or something else?

Comment: hi Derek F, i have not try summing because in SOQL can't do summing on child object. the relationship between Account and Expenses__c is lookup (one Account can have multiple cases m:1). all the case related to the same account should get the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer goes over a largely "no code" solution

The `Gross_Income__c` field on `Opportunity` can be taken care of by a rollup summary field.

The quickest and easiest way to sum the `Gross_Income__c` on `Expense__c` would probably be to use Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-w_ezvYjQAhUn6YMKHePXB8IQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fafawcett%2Fdeclarative-lookup-rollup-summaries&usg=AFQjCNFbgVBnZZYbDALgGLgr2r8VA1xctg&sig2=sADyZv1Kvcv61xKlSxYhSw).

From there, a simple formula field on `Account` can take care of subtracting the expenses from the rolled-up `Gross_Income__c` from the `Opportunities`

At that point, you could make a cross-object formula field on `Case` to pull the value of your formula field on `Account`.

If you're not interested on having this data on the `Account`, you could forego the formula field on the `Account`, and just do it in the formula field on the `Case` instead.

Comment: That i's good. However what if you have more than 10 fields to roll up?. I do understand that Salesforce has increased their roll-ups to 10 per object. Also, i only asked for one field in my post and that is a mislead from my end.

Comment: Salesforce increased the rollup summary field limit to 25 per sObject a while ago (Winter '16). The old limit was 10. Regardless, if you're out of rollup summary fields, you can use the DLRS tool.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your comment. Do you mean that you have more than one field that needs to be aggregated from `Opportunity` and `Expense__c`? If so, that would be good information to include in your question. This solution should be able to scale to a reasonable number of fields.

Comment: Hi Derek, yes i have more than one field that need to be aggregated from Opportunity and Expense__c. I did update the question to reflect that. thanks

Comment: With 30 fields, using DLRS to roll up values to the `Account` is still feasible. You'd simply need to apply the above to each of your 30 fields. It'll be a bit of a pain to set up, but that'd be the case for pretty much any solution that involves 30 fields. The big benefit to this approach is that (I believe) it's able to be maintained without requiring deployments (i.e. if you have one declarative rollup between 2 objects in production already, you can add more rollups directly in production).